# Frequently crashes in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 19.04, crash

I'm frequently experiencing crashes in Ubuntu 19.04 with nvidia 390.129 and dual monitors.
I've noted it happen aleatory, but more frequently when I'm customizing gnome extensions.
See bellow crash on second monitor, after that the system not respond and I need to reboot.
Can anyone give me some ideia about what's happening?

[image: nvid]

PS.: On second monitor the colors change and sometimes like mosaics :D

```
ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 28
drwxrwxr-x 7 diego diego 4096 ago 11 13:31 .
drwx------ 3 diego diego 4096 ago 11 22:08 ..
drwxrwxr-x 5 diego diego 4096 jul 26 22:32 arc-menu@linxgem33.com
drwxrwxr-x 5 diego diego 4096 jul 24 22:07 dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 2 diego diego 4096 jul 26 22:40 gnome-shutdown-button@kirby_33@hotmail.fr
drwxrwxr-x 5 diego diego 4096 ago 11 13:31 multi-monitors-add-on@spin83
drwxrwxr-x 3 diego diego 4096 jul 24 22:06 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

[Syslog*](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y0K3Q4Y4h2mlKkAB2irHC1pBISPGYvNi)

Comment: "more frequently when I'm customizing gnome extensions" -- which extensions?  Do the problems persist if you uninstall/purge these extensions?  Can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: `journalctl -b -1 -xe` will show you logs from the previous crash.

Comment: @Nmath, at least two times it happen when I'm customizing "Arc Menu" and "Multi monitors add-on", but in another times I was just using chrome and vscode...

Comment: @waltinator, this command just be used after a restart preceded of crash or any time? I mean, I've turned off normally other times after crash. Can I read fault logs at any time?

Comment: Yes, with `-b -2`, `-b -3`, etc. Also see `journalctl --list-boots`

Comment: You've probably got a bad GNOME Shell extension. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and if you look at `grep -i gnome-shell /var/log/syslog*` you can probably find the name of the bad extension. Report back.

Comment: Thank you @heynnema, I did it. I put syslog* in a txt because it have many lines...

Comment: In addition, some mouse locking/flicking are happen after dual monitor extension...

Comment: I've reviewed your GNOME Shell extension list and your syslog. The syslog is quite a mess! I think that you have multiple extension problems. You also have an older Nvidia driver that probably needs to be updated. For testing purposes, turn off ALL of your GNOME extensions, and run like that for a while. Monitor syslog with the last command that I gave you. GNOME Shell should NOT be generating all of that traffic. Later... if you've run ok for a while... enable ONE extension at a time... and run/monitor some more. Remember... two extensions could have a conflict together. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema, I've removed all extensions and apparently the crashes on second monitor was solved, but mouse flicker and slowless on the system continued... then because you told me about syslog is quite a mess, i decided to reinstall ubuntu using LTS version. There are no one more recently version for my GPU in PPA Graphics, the recent versions (430xx) doesn't work in my laptop. At last, I want to glad for your time and patience. Althought I continuos in doubt over what can cause mess in syslog. Thank you!!!

Comment: Well I'm not sure if it was a destine thing, but I have experienced right now a crash :( This time, I can't bring tty using Sysrq (REISUB). Have any suggestion?

Comment: I made two videos to show the problem:
1) (2:00) - https://photos.app.goo.gl/SShPB9o9c4PP73JAA
2) (2:10) - https://photos.app.goo.gl/SShPB9o9c4PP73JAA

Sorry for my poor english :D

Comment: Are all GNOME extensions still disabled, or did you narrow it down to one specific one that caused the problem on the 2nd monitor? The videos you left look the same. What are you trying to show me there?

Comment: I've disabled all extensions at gnome-tweaks. I think it is enough, right? Are there another way to do that?
I wanna show the moment exact where error happen and how the laptop stay. Maybe to offer some way to found the source...
I frequentely use, chrome-stable, vscode, terminal and nautilus. Sometimes, when I press CTRL + C in adress bar at nautilus, the crash happen.

Comment: I believe there is one extension I cannot restore the original. It is, dash to dock, look that my dash continuing in dock format.

Comment: To enable/disable GNOME extensions, you can use gnome-tweaks, or go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/. `Dash to Dock` has problems in 19.04. Do you have the latest version installed? What problem are you having? Also, please give more details about "Sometimes, when I press CTRL + C in adress bar at nautilus, the crash happen.". Is there any reason to use control+c in the address bar?

Comment: Well, I'll try remove dash to dock manually than. I've tryed to remove for Gnome extensions but don't worked. I frequenttly use CTRL + C to copy paths and paste in chrome when I'm navigating in directories where my sites are stored. In some days I post the result...

Comment: @heynnema, I think I've refined things. After to make a totally new installation (without extensions) and the problem continuous happening. I noted, it ever happen when I'm using nautilus and  ctrl + c in a path and ALT + TAB to change for another interface like a geditor.
There are no more extensions and none version of gpu driver for nvidia 525M. Have more any idea to share?
Thank you again!

Comment: Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This will take many hours to complete.

Comment: Also, check your BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Then go to the manufacturer's web site and see if there's a newer BIOS available.

Comment: I appreciate your help @heynnema. I'll try it, but honestly I don't believe it's the problem. Because, I'm using another OS like manjaro and windows in other partition and I haven't noted nothing like this.
I'll post my jornalctl for another review, if possible. I think I've found multiples of the same error happening instants before crash.
I forget to say memtest86 doesn't return error. Tks!!

Comment: @Diego OK, let me review the latest log files.

Comment: @heynnema, here is my recent log.txt https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ctogf2o4rxo8iQICnvC61H1KaVd2KVpL.
Pay attention in lines: 1182, 1221, 1222, 1223, 1359 and 1360. Almost all error are about GDBus.

Comment: @Diego I don't know. Sorry I can't be of more help :-(

Comment: Don't say sorry @heynnema :D :D. I'm glad for all try and patience... Thank you a lot!!!